# partial differential equation, classical formulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I got to find a classical equation for those 2 equations:
$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}(cos(x)u\prime(x) \phi\prime(x) -f(x)\phi(x))dx=0$$ with $$\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) $$ and $$\int_{B_1(0)}(-1+|x|^2)u(x)\Delta \phi(x)+f(x)\phi(x) dx=0$$ with$$ \phi\in C_0^{\infty}(B_1(0))$$.
I got no idea how to make these formulations.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you have derivatives of $\phi$ (first term of each of the integrals above), try to integrate by parts so that you pass the derivatives to other functions and you get just $\phi$.

Then use the boundary conditions and factor out $\phi$ to *isolate* the terms for the classical equation inside the integral.

For instance:
$$ 0= \int_{a}^{b} \big(f(x)u(x) \phi'(x) + g(x)\phi(x) \big)dx = f(x)u(x)\phi(x)\Bigg|_{a}^{b} -\int_{a}^{b} \phi(x)\Big(\big(f(x)u(x)\big)' - g(x)\Big)dx$$
and the equation would be
$$\big(f(x)u(x)\big)' - g(x) = 0,$$
once you have managed the boundary term.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I know how to deal with the second equation, but only if it's in one dimension. What happens when it has more dimensions because of $\Delta$ ?

Comment: It is a bit more tricky, but the procedure is the same. Use [Green's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_identities), which would be the multidimensional equivalent.